DaVinci Resolve - Text solid fill not shown in preview
I'm using DaVinci Resolve for quite a while. However, after I bought a new higher-spec laptop and downloaded the latest non-beta DaVinci Resolve 18.6, I found that the solid fill of texts of my previously editted video can't be shown in preview, while I'm sure that the solid fill is "enabled".
I'll never overexpress my gratitute for the solution to this.
